# Are "atomic" and "synchronous" synonyms in programming?

Tags: java, asynchronous, atomic, synchronous

Do "atomic" and "synchronous" mean the same thing or are there some minute differences?

Looking at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054086/what-does-atomic-mean-in-programming), I think the answer to my question is yes, they're synonyms. Are the following true in general?

- a synchronous operation will complete before the next operation starts
- an atomic operation is the same as a synchronous operation
- an asynchronous operation will complete at some point before or after the next operation starts

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not quite the same.  An *atomic* operation is one that can't be subdivided into smaller parts. So, in Java, assigning to an `int` is atomic: nothing can interrupt it, it either completes or doesn't.

A *synchronous* operation is one that *simulates* being atomic through some programming mechanism you invoke using the `synchronized` keyword.  The implementation of that can vary.So in a synchronized block, the run time system enforces what's called a *critical region* in which only one thread of control can pass at the same time.

Comment: Good answer I was just in the middle of writing the same  thing! :-)

Comment: Add more detail about his Async confusion too and this answer becomes complete.