# Atomic operation in multi threaded workld

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

Are atomic operations safe enough to use it in multi threaded app without causing race conditions and other concurrency issue ? Let say that we don't worry about visibility (we read/write everything from CPU).

Comment: Yes, Java provides a number of atomic types and operations.  What is your exact question?

Comment: First of all... what do you mean with "atomic operations"? Do you mean those, that are defined as atomically by the JLS or do you mean the Operations on e.g an [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "atomic" mean in programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054086/what-does-atomic-mean-in-programming)

Comment: By atomic operation I mean e.g i++  (where var 'i' is int), I am not talking about  AtomicVariable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are atomic operations safe enough to use it in multi threaded app
>   without causing race conditions and other concurrency issue?

Yes, java has strictly defined [memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model) (also known as [JSR 133](https://www.cs.umd.edu/users/pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html)).

There are also out-of-box atomic wrappers for primitive types in [java.util.concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package, like [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

Atomicity is implemented using [compare-and-swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap).

Comment: The question has nothing to do with Java in particular, but with the definition of atomicity. The memory model is irrelevant since OP explicitly said "we don't worry about visibility".

Comment: @Turing85 well OP added Java-tag, so he probably has a java project

Comment: @Turing85 I think OP is related to java as question was tagged with java..isn't?