# Is it safe for multiple threads to read a static object?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

None of the threads will be modifying the variable. They are all reading. Is this safe?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076461/how-does-c-sharp-guarantees-the-atomicity-of-read-write-operations

Comment: Depends what type the variable is. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/23/read-only-and-threadsafe-are-different.aspx

Comment: @PeterRitchie Can you elaborate on what information needs to be specified to make this question answerable?

Comment: @ta.speot.is Interesting! Thank you.

Comment: @ta.speot.is link is dead, fortunately the web archive preserved that classic: https://web.archive.org/web/20150523082529/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/23/read-only-and-threadsafe-are-different.aspx

Comment: And now on the actual Eric Lippert site: https://ericlippert.com/2011/05/23/read-only-and-threadsafe-are-different/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what resources are being shared by your threads. Consider the following example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int i;
    public int Foo { get { return i++; } } 
}

public static class SharedResources
{
    public static const string SharedString;
    public static readonly MyClass SharedMyClass;
}
```

In this code sample, the reference to `SharedString` is thread-safe, because strings are read-only in C#. However, any thread may call `SharedResources.SharedMyClass.Foo` at any time, and because increments are not thread safe (unless using [`Interlocked.Increment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), threads that read this property may get inconsistent results.

In short, if a class whose public API is read-only, but whose internals are not thread-safe, it's not safe simply have multiple threads reading from it.

Answer (score 1):

In order for concurrency bugs to surface, at least one access has to be a writing/modifying one.

Be careful not to mistake getters for a variable. They might have implications not known to you when accessing.

Comment: Is a deadlock a concurrency bug?  Deadlocks can happen with only reads if one or more of those reads triggers a static constructor that takes a lock.,

Comment: OK, my answer did not take deadlocks into consideration, only race conditions. Thx for that. They sure are concurrency bugs!

Comment: @EricLippert really loved your "Read-only and threadsafe are different" article - is it available somewhere in your new blog? (couldn't find it so went to web.archive)

Comment: @OhadSchneider: Thank you, I'm glad you enjoyed it.  You couldn't find it because it wasn't there. It is now! https://ericlippert.com/2011/05/23/read-only-and-threadsafe-are-different/

Comment: @EricLippert Beautiful! Added the link as a comment on the question as well :)