# Does using small datatypes (for example short instead of int) reduce memory usage?

Tags: c#, types, memory-management, short

My question is basically about how the C# compiler handles memory allocation of small datatypes. I do know that for example operators like add are defined on int and not on short and thus computations will be executed as if the shorts are int members.

Assuming the following:

- There's no business logic/validation logic associated with the choice of short as a datatype
- We're not doing anything with unsafe code

Does using the short datatype wherever possible reduce the memory footprint of my application and is it advisable to do so? Or is using short and the like not worth the effort as the compiler allocates the full memory ammount of a int32 for example and adds additional casts when doing arithmetic.

Any links on the supposed runtime performance impact would be greatly appreciated.

Related questions:

[Why should I use int instead of a byte or short in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097467/why-should-i-use-int-instead-of-a-byte-or-short-in-c)

[Integer summing blues, short += short problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343624/integer-summing-blues-short-short-problem)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From a memory-only perspective, using `short` instead of `int` will be better. The simple reason is that a `short` variable needs only half the size of an `int`  variable in memory. The CLR does not expand `short` to `int` in memory.

Nevertheless this reduced memory consumption might and probably will decrease runtime performance of your application significantly. All modern CPUs do perform much better with 32bit numbers than with 16bit numbers. Additionally in many cases the CLR will have to convert between `short` and `int` when e.g. calling methods that take `int` arguments. There are many other performance considerations you have to take before going this way.

I would only change this at very dedicated locations and modules of your application and only if you really encounter measurable memory shortages.

In some cases you can of course switch from `int` to `short` easily without hurting performance. One example is a giant array of `int`s all of which do also fit to `short`s.

Comment: Have you got some additional information about the runtime performance impact? Sure enough using short instead of int will decrease memory footprint but when it affects runtime performance in most cases it wouldn't be worth the effort.

Comment: @thekip: Have a look at the [Common Language 
Infrastructure (CLI) specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf). There are some elaborations regarding how `short` is handled at CLI level.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, chapter 12.1.2 says
The CLI defines an evaluation stack that contains either 4-byte or 8-byte integers; however, it also has a memory model that encompasses 1- and 2-byte integers.

So the stack only contains 4byte integers (thus int32 and not int16)?

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense *in terms of memory usage* only if you have in your program very large arrays (or collections built on arrays like `List<>`) of these types, or arrays of packed structs composed of same. By 'large' I mean that the total memory footprint of these arrays is a large percentage of the working set *and* a large percentage of the available memory. As for advisability, I'd venture that it is inadvisable to use short types unless the data your program operates on is explicitly specified in terms of `short` etc., or the volume of data runs into gigabytes.

Answer (score 1):

In short - yes. However you should also take care about memory alignment. You may find [Mastering C# structs](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84519/mastering-structs-in-c/) and [Memory alignment of classes in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951290/memory-alignment-of-classes-in-c) useful

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are using the shorts for. Also, are you allocating that many variables that the memory footprint is going to matter?

If this program was going to be used on a mobile device or a device with memory limitations then I might be concerned. However, most machines today are running at least 1-2 gb of ram an have pretty decent dual core processors. Also, most mobile devices today are becoming beast mini computers. If your declaring so much that that type of machine would start to die then you have a problem in your code already.

However, in response to the question. It can matter in memory limited machines if your declaring a lot of 4 byte variables when you only need a 2 byte variable to fill them then you should probable use the short.

If you preforming complicated calculations, square roots and such, or high value calculations. Then you should probably use variables with more bytes so you don't risk losing any data. Just declare what you need when you need it. Zero it out if your done with it to make sure C# cleans it up, if your worried about memory limitations.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to the machine language, at the registry level, I think it is better to align with the registry size as most of the move and arithmetic functions are done at the registry boundaries. If the machine has 32-bit registry set, it is better to align with 32-bit. If the machine has 16-bit registries for I/O operations, it is a good practice to align with 16-bit to reduce the number of operations in moving the content.

Comment: I think you mean "register" rather than "registry". And the question asked about memory usage, not speed of execution.