# Does using small datatypes reduce memory usage (From memory allocation not efficiency)?

Tags: java, c++, c, memory-management

Actually, my question is very similar with this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198240/does-using-small-datatypes-for-example-short-instead-of-int-reduce-memory-usag), but the post is focus on the C# only. Recently I read an article said that java will 'promote' some short types (like short) to 4 bytes in memory even if some bits are not used, so it can't reduce usage. (*is it true ?*)

So my question is how languages, especially **C, C++** and java (as Manish said in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531235/in-java-is-it-more-efficient-to-use-byte-or-short-instead-of-int-and-float-inst#) talked about java), handles **memory allocation** of small datatypes. **References** or any **approaches** to figure out it are preferred. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531235/in-java-is-it-more-efficient-to-use-byte-or-short-instead-of-int-and-float-inst

Comment: If your question is: is int8 type use less memory then int32? Yes, it does, because int8 only use 1 byte, and int32 use 4 bytes.

Comment: The size of a data type is only significant in structures and arrays.  Most languages will "promote" values to 32-64 bits in order to do computations, simply because that's the register size.

Comment: @Matt in practice that does not turn out to be quite accurate. Check the question and answers that Manish linked.

Comment: @Manish I am not mean performance or efficiency, just from the memory allocation.

Comment: (In general, Java will allocate locations for values that are equal to their theoretical size.  However, if you have, say, 3 `byte` values in an object, the JVM may align each on a 4-byte boundary.  For an array, though (except boolean), virtually all JVMs would allocate on a byte-for-byte basis.)

Comment: @Tony The question Manish referenced (and the related answers) cover both performance and memory implications. The memory usage is the first thing addressed in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14532302/676877

Comment: @BrettOkken and Manish Thanks to your reminder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C/C++ uses only the specified amount of memory but aligns the data (by default) to an address that is a multiple of some value, typically 4 bytes for 32 bit applications or 8 bytes for 64 bit.

So for example if the data is aligned on a 4 or 8 byte boundary then a "char" uses only one byte. An array of 5 chars will use 5 bytes. But the data item that is allocated after the 5 byte char array is placed at an address that skips 3 bytes to keep it correctly aligned.

This is for performance on most processors. There are usually pragmas like "pack" and "align" that can be used to change the alignment or disable it.

Comment: Depends on what's located after that 5-byte char array.  If it's more chars, no padding is needed, but if it's something like a 32-bit integer, it'll be moved up to the next 4-byte boundary so the 3 bytes after the char array are unused.

Comment: So any references about this ?

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++, different approaches may be taken depending on how you've requested the memory.

For `T* p = (T*)malloc(n * sizeof(T));` or `T* p = new T[n];` then the data will occupy `sizeof(T)*n` bytes of memory, so if `sizeof(T)` is reduced (e.g. to `int16_t` instead of `int32_t`) then that space is reduced accordingly.  That said, heap allocations tend to have some overheads, so few large allocations are better than a great many allocations for individual data items or very small arrays, where the overheads may be much more significant than small differences in `sizeof(T)`.

For structures, static and stack usage, padding is more significant than for large arrays, as the following data item might be of a different type with different alignment requirements, resulting in more padding.

At the other extreme, you can apply bitfields to effectively pack values into the minimum number of bits they need - very dense compression indeed, though you need to rely on compiler pragmas/attributes if you want explicit control - the Standard leaves it unspecified when a bitfield might start in a new memory "word" (e.g. 32 bit memory word for a 32 bit process, 64 for 64) or wrap across separate words, where in the words the bits hold data vs padding etc.).  Data types like C++ `bitset`s and `vector<bool>` may be more efficient than arrays of `bool` (which may well use an `int` for each element, but it's unspecified in the C++03 Standard).`

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).