# Defining an enumeration with default properties, Its effect on performance

Tags: c#, performance, byte, enumeration

Enumeration's default value is integer. However, when we use Enumeration we don't use so many values. So my questions are:

```
enum TYPE : byte{HORIZONTAL , DIAGONAL} //uses 1 byte

enum TYPE {HORIZONTAL , DIAGONAL} // int by default. Uses 4 bytes
```

  1)Does 3 byte space save us so much space? How does it effect nowadays computers?

  2)If yes, why its default value isn't byte?

  3)What should a good programmer do?

P.S I apologize for bad english it is not my native language.

Comment: It does not save space, unless you create large arrays of that enum.  Which ought to be exceedingly rare.  A corner case is the enum being used in a struct that has other members that are less than 4 bytes long.  And it is inefficient, extra machine code is required to convert the byte to *int* and back.  Processors really like their "native" type, which is *int* on all the ones that can execute .NET code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Does 3 byte space save us so much space? How does it effect nowadays computers?

Whether it actually saves space depends on a lot of other things. For example, if you use your enum as a field inside another class, things might (or might not) get memory aligned. I am not sure about the specifics in C# (even in C++ this can be a complex topic) - maybe [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951290/memory-alignment-of-classes-in-c) clarifies some things.

Even *if* it were guaranteed that using a `byte` enum always saves you three bytes, consider how many enum instances you use in a typical application. Ten? One hundred? Maybe a thousand? We are talking in the order of kilobytes here, while modern computers have at least gigabytes of RAM, that is 6 order of magnitude more.

> 2) If yes, why its default value isn't byte?

This is a decision by the team that designed C#, we can only assume they had their reasons.

Yes, a `byte` can only hold values up to 255. Now probably most enumerations don't have more than 255 values, but for example for `Flags` `enum`s that only gives you 8 possible flags and you may need more. Also, since `enum`s are basically just integer numbers, you want to be able to do integer or bitwise operations on them (like `+` or `|`) -- again this is especially true if you have enum `Flags` -- and those work on full 32- or 64-bit integers anyway. In fact they may even be *slower* for `byte`s because the value has to be expanded to a full integer and then truncated again.

> 3) What should a good programmer do?

As usual, unless you are writing performance or memory critical applications, don't worry about it. Especially in C# with its smart compilers, it is easy to apply premature "optimizations" that actually *slow down* the performance, so unless you have very convincing evidence that you actually *need* those three extra bytes, just write the code for legibility and not for speed. Even *if* the theoretical 3 byte difference actually turns out to be there in practice, you probably lose a multitude of that in other "inefficiencies" such as padded classes, inefficient string operations, copies of local variables, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, this is a really nice explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I've never experienced an issue defining `Enums` with default Integral type, and you seem not to have an issue yourself. If you ever experience a memory issue in your system it is more likely that it is caused by other issues and not by choosing int over byte for your `Enums`.

Those little micro-Enhancements has rare impact in today's cheap memory computers.

Unless you're working on embedded systems with limited memory, try not to focus on those micro-optimizations.